# How can I get the referring page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a back button in a toolbar in jquery mobile for an iOS ap. The problem is that you can get to the same page through different ways so I can't just statically program where the back button should go. Is there a way to figure out how I was referred to each page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the attribute data-rel="back" on an anchor, any clicks on that anchor will mimic the back button, going back one history entry and ignoring the anchor's default href.

Also, please keep in mind that if you just want a reverse transition without actually going back in history, you should use the data-direction="reverse" attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the referrer url i suggest what you can do is pass in as a query parameter
eg. `location.href = <destination url> + '?referrer=' + <current page url>;`

Comment: jQuery Mobile works in such a way (by default at least) as to render query strings useless.

Comment: itsmequinn you are right if its an internal/embedded page, it work well for me because the pages are individual pages.